# How to control draw of NSTableView's vertical line?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How to control draw of NSTableView's vertical line?
for example. which table column can draw vertical line, which cannot?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The grid is drawn by the NSTableView itself.

You need to overwrite

`- (void)drawGridInClipRect:(NSRect)aRect`

in order to have custom drawing.